# Exception when I divide by 0 on xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Can someone point me in the right direction I've read a few other methods of how to throw exceptions but none seem to work. The idea is to bind the Loan, Interest & Length to entry's on the xaml. & Total will obviusly bind to a label depending on what the users input.

```
 private int loanAmount { get; set; }
        public int Loan
        {
            get => loanAmount;
            set
            {

                loanAmount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Loan");
                CalculateAPR();
            }

        }


        private int intRate { get; set; }
        public int Interest
        {
            get => intRate;
            set
            {

                intRate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Interest");
                CalculateAPR();
            }

        }

        private int loanLength { get; set; }
        public int Length
        {
            get => loanLength;
            set
            {

                loanLength = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Length");
                CalculateAPR();
            }

        }


        private string total { get; set; }
        public string Total
        {
            get => total;
            set
            {

                total = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Total");
            }
        }



    public void CalculateAPR()
        {
            Total = "£" + (Loan * Length) / Interest;

        }
    }
```

Comment: `Total = "£" + Interest == 0 ? 0 : (Loan * Length) / Interest;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things here:

- I would recommend making the interest rate a `double` so that you can represent fractional interest rates.
- APR is computed by multiplying the number of periods in a year, not by the length (in what?)  If the "Rate" is monthly, then multiply interest by 12.
- If you want to show an error when the interest value hasn't been set, you could make Interest nullable (`int?`) and do something like this: `Total = Interest.HasValue ? "£" + (Interest * 12) : "-";`

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that your interest is not 0. Obviously the equation `(loan * length) / interest` is not evaluable if your interest is 0.

You can try to use one of the following solutions.

First solution:

```cs
public void CalculateAPR()
{
    if(Interest != 0) {
        Total = "£" + (Loan * Length) / Interest;
    } else {
        Total = "£ -";
    }
}
```

Second solution:

```cs
private int? intRate { get; set; }
public int? Interest
{
    get => intRate;
    set {
        intRate = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Interest");
        CalculateAPR();
    }
}

public void CalculateAPR()
{
    Total = "£" + (Loan * Length) / (Interest??1);
}
```

Depending on how you expect the total label to look like, if your interest is not filled yet.

Answer (score 0):

## If you're trying to throw

```
public void CalculateAPR()
{
   if(Interest == 0) throw new ApplicationException("Interest must not be zero!");
   Total = "£" + (Loan * Length) / Interest;
}
```

## If you're trying to handle

```
public void CalculateAPR()
{
   if(Interest == 0) 
   {
        Total = "...";
   }
   else 
   {
        Total = "£" + (Loan * Length) / Interest;
   }
}
```

or

```
public void CalculateAPR()
{
   try
   {
      Total = "£" + (Loan * Length) / Interest;
   }
   catch (DivideByZeroException) 
   {
        Total = "...";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the interest rate is `0`, then the `APR` is also `0`. So just check for that case before trying to do the division:

```
public void CalculateAPR()
{
    Total = "£" + Interest == 0 ? 0 : (Loan * Length) / Interest;
}
```